# How would I go about hosting a discord C# (net.core) discord bot?

Tags: c#, heroku, .net-core, bots, discord

First of all i wanna say that im pretty clueless when it comes to this.

Okay, so using Visual studio i made a C# net.core Discord bot for a channel, it works just like i want it to. Got a SQL database, bunch of modules etc etc.  But now i've reached a roadblock:

1) I've never worked with net.core projects and i've no idea how to run the bot without having to launch visual studio everytime, there's no exe or bat files and i haven't found a way to generate it, how should i go about this?

2) I want to host the bot so it's active 24/7 and that i wouldnt need to turn it on, i saw a website called "Heroku" which works with GitHub repositories, but i've no idea where to even begin.

I've been looking for tutorials and guides on how to do this but every one of them either doesn't explain it well enough for a clueless pleb like me  or uses Javascript or other things that is not really relevant.

Anyway, I hope I can receive some answers, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately Heroku doesn't support .Net Core (or .Net in general for that matter). Best hosting options are likely going to be AWS or Azure.

Comment: Alright,  i'll look into that, thank you